# Get the Excel xlGeneralFormatName in C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I'm trying to get the

```
xlGeneralFormatName
```

From Excel, like this:

```
        Excel.Application _excelApp;
        Excel.Workbook _excelWB;

        _excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        _excelWB = _excelApp.Workbooks.Add();

        object o  = _excelWB.Application.International(Excel.XlApplicationInternational.xlGeneralFormatName);
```

but I'm getting a **Cannot invoke a non-delegate type error** on the last line of code.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`International` is a property, not a method. See [**_Application.International Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.international.aspx).

Perhaps you are new to C#? You get a member of an indexed property using square brackets, not parenthesis:

```
object o = _excelWB.Application.International[Excel.XlApplicationInternational.xlGeneralFormatName];
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks - you beat me to it.